# Partial fraction in Laplace transform

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

When watching the Laplace Transform video by Gilbert Strang, I encountered a problem:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(s-a)(s-c)}=\frac{1}{(s-c)(c-a)}+\frac{1}{(s-a)(a-c)}
\end{equation}

How did he do that? I've learnt partial fraction, but have no idea how to do that.

Thanks for help!

Comment: By partial fraction decomposition $\frac{1}{(s-a)(s-c)}=\frac{A}{(s-c)}+\frac{B}{(s-a)}$. Now find $A$ and $B$.

Comment: What _do_ you get when you work out the partial fraction decomposition for the left side? (Surely you've worked it out, right?)

Comment: It actually does not work out using the normal decomposition method as I've tried. The system of equation I end up with will be $A+B=0$ and $Aa+Bc=-1$, which I have no idea how to do.

Comment: Then $B=-A$ and by plugging it into the other one we find $A$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be derived using a simple trick:

$$
\frac{1}{(s-a)(s-c)}=\frac{(c-a)}{(c-a)(s-a)(s-c)} $$ 
$$=\frac{(s-a)-(s-c)}{(c-a)(s-a)(s-c)} =\frac{1}{(s-c)(c-a)}-\frac{1}{(s-a)(c-a)}
$$
$$=\frac{1}{(s-c)(c-a)}+\frac{1}{(s-a)(a-c)}$$

Comment: Thanks! I get it mow.

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

Recall that:
 $$\frac{1}{s-c}-\frac{1}{s-a}=\frac{c-a}{(s-a)(s-c)}$$